# How to use Internet explorer as browser in mchanize

Tags: python, web-scraping, mechanize

```
import mechanize
import cookielib
br = mechanize.Browser()    
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

# Browser options
br.set_handle_equiv(True)    
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=5)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Chrome')]

url1 = 'www.google.com'
br.open(url1)
```

here I tried to open the link with chrome. if I want to use internet explorer what changes I have to made here.

Comment: What part of this code is trying to use Chrome? The user agent doesn't control which browser is used

Comment: br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Chrome')]

Comment: But the link is opening always in chrome. how can I do it Internet explorer.

Answer (score 0):

IE is worked on Trident (MSHTML) browser engine. Please try this code.

```
import sys
from mechanize import Browser
br = Browser()

br.set_handle_robots( False )
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; AS; rv:11.0) like Gecko')]

url = str(sys.argv[1])
filename = str(sys.argv[2])

f = br.retrieve(url,filename)[0]
```

Also, of course, you can open your IE, and get UserAgent string in JavaScript console. Open Developer Tools (`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `j`, `F12` on different machines) and run in JS console this code: `navigator.userAgent;`.